# gulp-usemin multiple html files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I made multiple html files in my repository für different views of my site:

- index.html
- news.html
- page.html

But my gulp build task only build one of the files not all.

```
gulp.task('build:usemin', ['build:cleanfolder', 'build:cleanfiles'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(useMin({
        css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
        js: [minifyJs(), 'concat'],
        html: [minifyHtml({collapseWhitespace: true})]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath));
    return stream;
});
```

Has anybody an idea how I can fix it?
Thanks.

My full gulpfile.js

```
////////////////////
// Modules
////////////////////
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sassLint = require('gulp-sass-lint'),
    jsHint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    minifyJs = require('gulp-uglify'),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    minifyHtml = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    minifyImages = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    useMin = require('gulp-usemin'),
    del = require('del'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


////////////////////
// Constants
////////////////////
const distPath = './dist';


////////////////////
// Tasks
////////////////////

// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sassLint({
            options: {
                formatter: 'stylish',
                configFile: './.sass-lint.yml'
            },
        }))
        .pipe(sassLint.format())
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'))
});

// Check JavaScripts
gulp.task('scripts-check', function() {
    gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jsHint())
    .pipe(jsHint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
});

// Browsersync
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './src/'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts-check']);
    gulp.watch('./src/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/*.html', './src/css/*.css', './src/js/*.js']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Serve
gulp.task('serve', ['sass', 'scripts-check', 'browser-sync', 'watch']);


////////////////////
// Build Tasks
////////////////////
gulp.task('build:cleanfolder', function() {
    return del(distPath).then(paths => {
        console.log('Deleted files and folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
    });
});

gulp.task('build:copyfiles', ['build:cleanfolder'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src([
        'src/**',
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath));
    return stream;
});

gulp.task('build:cleanfiles', ['build:copyfiles'], function() {
    return del([
        distPath + '/**/*.html',
        distPath + '/sass',
        distPath + '/css',
        distPath + '/js',
        distPath + '/images',
        distPath + '/bower_components'
    ])
    .then(paths => {
        console.log('Deleted files and folders:\n', paths.join('\n'));
    });
});

gulp.task('build:usemin', ['build:cleanfolder', 'build:cleanfiles'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(useMin({
        css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
        js: [minifyJs(), 'concat'],
        html: [ function(){ return minifyHtml({collapseWhitespace: true});} ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath));
    return stream;
});

gulp.task('build:minify-images', ['build:cleanfolder', 'build:cleanfiles'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./src/images/**/*.{png,gif,jpg,svg}')
    .pipe(minifyImages())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath + '/images'));
    return stream;
});

gulp.task('build:sass', ['build:cleanfolder', 'build:cleanfiles'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath + '/css'))
    return stream;
});

gulp.task('build:serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: distPath
        },
        notify: false
    });
});

gulp.task('build', ['build:sass', 'build:usemin', 'build:minify-images']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-usemin)

> If you need to call the same pipeline twice, you need to define each task as a function that returns the stream object that should be used.

Therefore:

```
gulp.task('build:usemin', ['build:cleanfolder', 'build:cleanfiles'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src('./src/**/*.html')
    .pipe(useMin({
        css: [minifyCss(), 'concat'],
        js: [minifyJs(), 'concat'],
        html: [ function(){ return minifyHtml({collapseWhitespace: true});} ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath));
    return stream;
});
```

Comment: And how can I call my function then often?

Comment: Use the snippet I posted. It returns a function rather than the result itself, so the stream can continue.

Comment: Can you post your full GulpFile.js. I recreated your file and it works on my end.

Comment: Fixed it or added the whole GulpFile.js?

Comment: I added the whole Gulpfile.

Comment: Ok I ran that GulpFile with `index.html`, `news.html` and `page.html` in the ./src/ directory and it outputted all three to the dist folder.

Comment: Okay, I make it from hand and find an other solution at the next project. Stupid plugin...
But thanks for your efforts.